# Created my own string class -- errors with overloaded assignment operator and destructor

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, destructor

Created my own string class and it unexpectedly breaks when it calls the overloaded assignment operator (i.e. I believe).  It breaks exactly when it tries to delete mStr after the overloaded assignment operator are called.

The mStr being deleted is "\nPlatinum: 5 \nGold: 5 \nSilver: 6 \nCopper: 5 "

What am I doing wrong and how can I make sure my program does not break with no memory leaks??

**Code breaks here**

```
String::~String()
{
delete [] mStr;
mStr = nullptr;
}
```

**Code breaks right before here**

```
    String tempBuffer;

    //Store entire worth of potions
    tempBuffer = "Platinum: ";
    tempBuffer += currencyBuffer[0];
    tempBuffer += "\nGold: ";
    tempBuffer += currencyBuffer[1];
    tempBuffer += "\nSilver: ";
    tempBuffer += currencyBuffer[2];
    tempBuffer += "\nCopper: ";
    tempBuffer += currencyBuffer[3];

    mCost = tempBuffer;
```

**Overloaded assignment operator**

```
String &String::operator=(const String & rhs)
{
//Check for self-assignment
if(this != &rhs)
{
    //Check if string is null
    if(rhs.mStr != nullptr)
    {
        //Delete any previously allocated memory
        delete [] this->mStr;

        //Deep copy
        this->mStr = new char[strlen(rhs.mStr) + 1];
        strcpy(this->mStr, rhs.mStr);
    }
    else
        this->mStr = nullptr;
}

//Return object
return *this;
}
```

**Overloaded add and assign operator**

```
String &String::operator+=( String rhs)
{
//Check for self-assignment
if(this != &rhs)
{
    //Convert to cString
    char * buffer = rhs.c_str();

    //Find length of rhs
    int length = strlen(buffer);

    //Allocate memory
    char * newSize = new char[length + 1];

    //Copy into string
    strcpy(newSize, buffer);

    //Concatenate
    strcat(this->mStr, newSize);

    //Deallocate memory
    delete [] newSize;

}

//Return object
return *this;
}
```

**Copy Constructor**

```
String::String(const String & copy)
:mStr()
{
*this = copy;
}
```

**String Constructor**

```
String::String(char * str)
{
//Allocate memory for data member
mStr = new char[strlen(str) + 1];

//Copy str into data member
strcpy(mStr, str);
}
```

**String Constructor for Characters**

```
String::String(char ch)
{
//Assign data member and allocate space
mStr = new char[2];

//Assign first character to the character
mStr[0] = ch;

//Assign second character to null
mStr[1]= '\0';
}
```

Comment: Making the string class is hw, but that was the only direction.  Here's the UML, build a string class.  All the code is mine.  It is to use our own string class for our RPG we have to build all semester.

Comment: What is the definition of the default constructor?

Comment: The definition of the default constructor is 

    String::String()
 :mStr()
    {}

EDIT: How do I make code blocks in the comment section??  The ``'s aren't working for me.

Comment: Handle memory management of a buffer in a separate class, like using `std::vector`, or your own `buffer` class with a `resize` method.  Then write your pretty operators in your string class.  Mixing low level memory management in with a bunch of high level operator overloading is a bad idea, and will lead to bugs.

Answer (score 2):

- Possible memory leak in `operator=()` as `this->mStr` is assigned to `nullptr` without `delete[]` if `rhs` contains a `nullptr`.
- In `operator+=()` `this->mStr` is not being extended prior to concatentation. This means the `strcat()` will be writing to memory it should not be, causing undefined behaviour and may be the cause of the problem witnessed in the destructor.

Comment: So you're saying I didn't allocate room for this->mStr??  So 

`  //Allocate room for newSize
  this->mStr = new char [strlen(newSize) + 1];`

Comment: @gongzhitaao, it is unnecessary as `delete[] nullptr` is a no-op.

Comment: Also if `this->mStr = new char[strlen(rhs.mStr) + 1];` **throws** this->mStr  is lost and class will be in an invalid state. Maybe he should use local copy of `this->mStr` and delete after making sure everything is ok.

Comment: @MrPickle5, in `operator+()` the `this->mStr` must be large enough to hold the current content plus the incoming content. Allocate a new buffer big enough, copy both into it, delete mstr and assign mstr to the new buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume this is an exercise (otherwise you'd use `std::string`). Your problem appears to be that `operator+=` only allocates enough space for the string that you're adding, *not* enough space for both the original string and the new piece you apprend to its end. You'd need to allocate more space: `char * newSize = new char[strlen(this->mStr) + length + 1];`, then delete the old string pointer and assign the `newSize` pointer to the class member.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Unfortunately, it still breaks when it calls the destructor to delete tempBuffer.

I added your code deleted newSize and then assigned the newSize pointer. `newSize = this->mStr`.